# How do I set the x-axis equal? No scaling

Tags: tikz-pgf

In the example below, the x-axis has the range beginning with 0 up to 10. Now, I want an x-axis where the ticks don't scale like the numbers. What I mean is I would like to plot the data, where I have 4 ticks, which are labeled with the corresponding index (1,2,3,10) but have all the same gap.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

% example data file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datafile.dat}
    index value1 value2
    1 1 2
    2 2 3
    3 3 4
    10 4 5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xlabel=index,
        ylabel=values,
        ]

        \addplot table[x=index,y=value1] {datafile.dat};
        \addplot table[x=index,y=value2] {datafile.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So, what answer meets your requirements?

Comment: Is there any other concern about the original question or on the answers proposed so far?

Answer (score 2):

In order for the ticks in `x-axis` to have the same gap, what comes to mind is to alter the data like this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{datafile.dat}
    index value1 value2
    1 1 2
    2 2 3
    3 3 4
    4 4 5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        %axis equal,
        xtick=\empty,
        extra x ticks={1,2,3,4},
        extra x tick labels={1,2,3,10},
        xlabel=index,
        ylabel=values,
        ]
        \addplot table[x=index,y=value1] {datafile.dat};
        \addplot table[x=index,y=value2] {datafile.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

So the plot will look like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Note that I also added the following lines to axis options:

```
%axis equal,
xtick=\empty,
extra x ticks={1,2,3,4,5},
extra x tick labels={1,2,3,$\cdots$,10},
```

(You can take off the `%` symbol to see what happens with axes scales, so then you can decide which option to use).

---

And this is an **alternate solution** (which I'd prefer):

[image]
With the code

```
\begin{filecontents}{datafile.dat}
    index value1 value2
    1 1 2
    2 2 3
    3 3 4
    5 4 5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[%
        axis equal,
        xtick=\empty,
        extra x ticks={1,2,3,4,5},
        extra x tick labels={1,2,3,$\cdots$,10},
        xlabel=index,
        ylabel=values,
        ]
        \addplot table[x=index,y=value1] {datafile.dat};
        \addplot table[x=index,y=value2] {datafile.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

---

**P.S.:** It is recommended to always include the following line in the preamble, whenever you use `pgfplots` package

```
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add `xtick=data` and `xticklabels from table={datafile.dat}{index}` to the axis options. Then you can replace `x=index` by `x expr=\coordindex` in the plot options to get

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}% current version is 1.15

% example data file
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datafile.dat}
  index value1 value2
  1 1 2
  2 2 3
  3 3 4
  10 4 5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xlabel=index,
    ylabel=values,
    xtick=data,% <- added
    xticklabels from table={datafile.dat}{index}% <- added
    ]

    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y=value1] {datafile.dat};% <- changed
    \addplot table[x expr=\coordindex,y=value2] {datafile.dat};% <- changed
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```